# AWS eventbridge rule unable to hit API gateway Endpoint with 403:NO_PERMISSIONS Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-event-bridge

I have already built an API gateway that I can hit from other applications with IAM credentials. This has been tested and works.

When setting up an eventbridge rate rule I have the following settings

1. Event Schedule - Fixed rate of 2 minutes
2. Targets

   - Target Name - api id/prod/*/healthCheck
   - Type - API Gateway
   - Arn - arn:aws:execute-api:region:account:api id/prod/*/healthCheck
   - input - Matched event
   - Role Permissions (admin temporary)

I set up a DLQ because all of the invocations were failing and I was able to see that I am getting a 403 permissions error on the invocations. However, to check for permissions I temporarily gave admin as shown above and I still get this error.

What is going on here? I'm really confused on this one.

Update:
I found [this](https://repost.aws/questions/QUF6vrV82RQDe7__jyGFK7cg/how-to-invoke-a-private-rest-api-created-with-aws-gateway-endpoint-from-an-event-bus-rule) resource that states event bus cannot hit private endpoints, but my endpoint for this API is set to regional, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: I didn't have a resource policy added to my API as mentioned in the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-use-resource-based.html#eb-api-gateway-permissions, but that didn't fix the issue either.

Comment: What was the 403 error type?

Comment: It was "No permissions"

Comment: Specifically here is the entire error message `Got status code "403" while trying to invoke "GET https://<api-id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/prod/%2FhealthCheck". (Service: api_gateway; Status Code: 403; Error Code: Forbidden; Request ID: c45291dd-367a-4689-9882-27e1654820a4; Proxy: null)`

Comment: Couple of things to check. The path (in the error) has an encoded /, so it's https://<api-id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/prod//healthCheck. Is that // expected? Or you need to pass a path parameter in there? Also, do you have WAF enabled in the API Gateway? If yes, it could be blocking the request due to that double //

Comment: good catch. I set the path parameters to just "healthCheck" and now I'm getting a similar error, but it doesn't show the path at all. `Got status code "403" while trying to invoke "GET https://k1q56tt2uh.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com". (Service: api_gateway; Status Code: 403; Error Code: Forbidden; Request ID: a8a27d66-a1ec-4b47-a78a-4bfa21b80c3c; Proxy: null)`

Comment: Should be right I think. HEre is the target ARN `arn:aws:execute-api:<region>:<account-id>:<api-id>/prod/GET/*` and the pathParameter values `["healthCheck"]`

Comment: bypassing api gateway and sending directly to the lambda function sitting behind it works. I am still confused why the api won't work.